# How do I protect header rows but allow to enter new rows using AXLSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, axlsx

I am working with  'Axlsx' gem in rails , but didn't got how to protect some special column in that excel .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is specify an unlocked style and apply it to all rows that should not be protected.
I know it is a bit convoluted, but then so is the specification!

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

unlocked = wb.styles.add_style { locked: false }

wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Sheet Protection') do |sheet|
  sheet.sheet_protection.password = 'fish'
  sheet.add_row [1, 2 ,3] # These cells will be locked
  sheet.add_row [4, 5, 6], style: unlocked # these cells will not!
end

p.serialize 'dont_touch_my_headers.xlsx'
```

The important thing to remember is that you need to specify a style for all non-header rows that includes

```
locked: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify locked in a style, then apply that style to the column at the end:

```
locked = wb.styles.add_style :locked => true
sheet.col_style 2, locked
```

I've not tested that. It combines a few examples. Here is an example of locking a single row:

https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb#L571

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. noel.
But whenever i add sheet.sheet_protection.password = 'XYZ'.        for protection with locked,unlocked
it protected my whole axlsx. But i wants to protect only my header row not all.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was that I checked the `sheet.sheet_protection` method and see the some useful method:

```
[5] pry(#<ProductsGrid>)> sheet.sheet_protection
=> #<Axlsx::SheetProtection:0x007f8a36173730
 @auto_filter=true,
 @delete_columns=true,
 @delete_rows=true,
 @format_cells=true,
 @format_columns=true,
 @format_rows=true,
 @insert_columns=true,
 @insert_hyperlinks=true,
 @insert_rows=true,
 @objects=false,
 @password=nil,
 @pivot_tables=true,
 @scenarios=false,
 @select_locked_cells=false,
 @select_unlocked_cells=false,
 @sheet=true,
 @sort=true>
```

and used one of them, just like i use in the Microsoft Excel. Here below is my

```
unlocked  = product_book.styles.add_style locked: false
product_sheet = product_book.add_worksheet(name: 'Product') do |sheet|
  sheet.sheet_protection.password = 'password'
  sheet.sheet_protection.select_locked_cells  = true
  sheet.add_row set_product_header, style: wrap_text
end
```

After inserting the row, apply style `unlocked` the the rest of the rows

Comment: One comment: The flags (un)set the protection. To allow the autofilter on a protected sheet, you must set `auto_filter=false` (meaning the protection of the autofilter is off, the action is allowed).

Comment: I don't set the option. I just want to show that there are options when we call this methods `sheet.sheet_protection`

Comment: Yes, and this helped me a lot. I just wanted to help others and leave a hint,  if they run into the same troubles then me.